# Dividing words from text starting with a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to test each word from a text if it starts with the character # if it does, i will put the word in variable 'response' if not, i will continue searching.
I tried something like :

```
var found = false;
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
     if (found = /^#...$/.test(text[i])) {
        found = true;
     }
     if (found== true){
          //other stuff
     }
}
```

could you help me with this one ?

Comment: `each word` Define what you mean by "word". Sequence of non-space? Sequence of English alphabet (and ignore the rest of the languages)?

Comment: A word like in the english alphabet, a non-space sequence as you mentioned.

Comment: Non-space sequence can contain digit, punctuation, characters from all languages etc. A sequence of English alphabet will **exclude** digits, punctuation and characters from languages other than English (the list is not exhausted).

Comment: How is that helping me actually ?

Comment: Depending on the definition, you will get different result. Just take the input `#abc!program something` for example - you get `$abc!program` with the non-space definition, and `#abc` (or maybe none) with the English alphabet definition.

Comment: I think you are kidding me, i just wanted to split sequences just like in the first answer, i find your comments very useless.

Comment: The answer split the string at spaces, which uses the definition that a word is a non-space sequence. With that definition, given the input `#];23;4 #word`, you include `#];23;4` as a "word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split on space, and then use substring to find the first letter. Then compare it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NzVS/1/)

```
var arr= text.split(' ');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].substring(0,1) == '#') {
        console.log('found!: ' + arr[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arr will contain only the first word ? can you explain it a little to me please ?

Comment: Arr will be an array - containing every word in the string. The for loop iterates the array. The substring(0,1) returns the first letter of the current word. Then that is compared to '#'. If that's true it will go inside the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
var found = false, response;
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
     if (/^#.*$/.test(text[i])) {
        found = true;
        response = text[i];
        break;
     }
}
```

That matches everything that starts with a `#`. If you just want to match non-space characters, use the RegEx `/^#(\S)*$/`

Comment: I guess the break; doesn't makes sense in this case, since i want all the words starting with # to be manipulated one by one.